iText and BouncyCastle Type Bind Conflicts
I have NET Core 5.0 project that contains itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter library 8.0.4 for work with PDF and TIFF files. This adapter contains self-implemented BouncyCastle (with same namespaces as in a original BC project). Of course I have another library that has link to original BouncyCastle.NetCore.


The main problem I have is type bind conflict in case of using HashSet:

Error CS0433  The type 'HashSet' exists in both 'BouncyCastle.Crypto,
Version=1.8.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and
'bc-fips-1.0.2, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'

As recommended by Microsoft, I tried to use Alias for iText7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter but still have the error due to Alias does not apply to assembly references.
What can I do in this situation? All two libraries (which contains BouncyCastle) are proprietary, not open-source projects, so I can't edit their references and create own builds

"Of course I have another library that has link to original BouncyCastle.NetCore." - Thus, you likely are not working FIPS conform anyways. So why not use the itext.bouncy-castle-adapater instead of the itext.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter?

So, now I have problem of conflicts BouncyCastle.Cryptography and BounceCastle.NetCore.
Error CS0433 The type 'PemReader' exists in both 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'BouncyCastle.Cryptography, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=072edcf4a5328938'
